# How to setup an open source USB token for testing iText 7 digital signature feature?

Tags: ssl, openssl, usb, itext7, pkcs#11

So basically the feature is to digitally sign a PDF using a USB token.
Digitally signing code is present on Page 96 in this iText [guide](https://itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/2018-12/digitalsignatures20130304.pdf).
Also, [this](https://git.itextsupport.com/projects/I7JS/repos/signatures/browse/src/test/java/com/itextpdf/samples/signatures/chapter04/C4_02_SignWithPKCS11USB.java#66) iText repo.

**How can I setup an open source USB token on Mac OS** for testing.
Would I have to buy any of the USB token which are compatible with OpenSC mentioned [here](https://github.com/OpenSC/OpenSC/wiki/Supported-hardware-%28smart-cards-and-USB-tokens%29#usb-tokens)?

Below link assumes that .so file is already present.
https://developers.yubico.com/YubiHSM2/Usage_Guides/OpenSSL_with_pkcs11_engine.html

Comment: Your "[iText 7 guide](https://itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/2018-12/digitalsignatures20130304.pdf)" is an iText 5 guide (for versions 5.3.x through 5.5.x).

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing. A token's pkcs#11 `.so` file is like a driver and it's usually provided by the token's manufacturer, so your are not supposed to create one. Also, there is no such thing as "self-signed .so file". Maybe you meant a self-signed certificate?

Comment: @LucasMartins yes you are right. I was confused with that. There is a engine_pkcs11.so file that was created while setting up OpenSC, is that the correct pkcs#11 .so file? Also is there any way I can create a USB token like how we create self signed certificates using OpenSSL? I'm sorry for the questions, I'm new to crypto.

Comment: @mkl thanks for pointing that out. I have added a repo now as well.

Comment: If you don't have a physical token, you can try to use a soft token, like this one: https://github.com/kinnalru/soft-pkcs11 (I never used it, so I don't know if it works).  This soft token has its own pkcs11 (you can find in the documentation how to use it). It's important to say that you should use soft tokens only for testing purposes.